# JPA @MapsId causes issues with nested Embeddables

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am trying to access a database with JPA and therefore need to create a few POJOs. Unfortunately, there are composited primary keys, which are also nested in each other. (Don't blame me for that one.)

In the end, I have a composited foreign key, which is a subset of my composited primary key.

For Example:

```
DeliveryDetail(*PERSONID*, *ADDRESSID*, *DELIVERYID*, *DELIVERYDETAILID*,...)
Delivery(      *PERSONID*, *ADDRESSID*, *DELIVERYID*, ...)
Address(       *PERSONID*, *ADDRESSID*, ...)
Person(        *PERSONID*, ...)
```

I'm using EmbeddedIds so create the composite primary keys. To save some redundant code, I tried to embed the AddressId into the DeliveryId and the DeliveryId into the DeliveryDetailId.

```
@Embeddable
public class DeliveryDetailId {

    @Embedded
    private DeliveryId deliveryId;

    @Column(name = "DETAILID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL")
    private int detailId;

}

@Embeddable
public class DeliveryId {

    @Embedded
    public AddressId addressId;

    @Column(name = "DELIVERYID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL")
    public int deliveryId;
}

@Embeddable
public class AddressId {

    @Column(name = "PERSONID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "CHAR")
    private String personId;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESSID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL")
    public int addressId;
}
```

This is where the fun starts.
JPA doesn't seem to like the nesting too much. If I try to to map my Delivery to my DeliveryDetails with the following construct, my Predeployment fails with a very unspecific NullPointerException.

```
@Entity
public class DeliveryDetail {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DeliveryDetailId deliveryDetailId;

    @MapsId("deliveryId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Delivery delivery;
}
```

I tried to add the JoinColumns to my MapsId annotation but it didn't make a difference. Or, to be more precise, die told me that I forgot at least one JoinColumn. (I added all three)

It seems so work, when I don't embed my AddressId in my DeliveryId and instead just copy the two columns. I don't know whether the nesting itself is the problem or where I just did it wrong.

What would be the best practice to build such a construct with the composite fk in the composite pk with JPA?
My fallback would be to just embed a maximum of one layer. So far it looks like that should work but it is a huge project aber it would add a lot of redundancies.

Just in case it is helpful in any way, here is the Exception. Do me, it's not worth a lot.

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@15da254
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [deliveryDb] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.example.DbEntityManagerFactory.getFactory(DbEntityManagerFactory.java:15)
    at com.example.TestDataGenerator.setUp(TestDataGenerator.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [deliveryDb] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2080)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2071)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:104)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [deliveryDb] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.addFieldNameTranslation(MappingAccessor.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.EmbeddedAccessor.updateDerivedIdField(EmbeddedAccessor.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processMapsIdFields(ObjectAccessor.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processMapsId(ObjectAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOwningMappingKeys(ObjectAccessor.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToOneAccessor.process(ManyToOneAccessor.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processDerivedId(ClassAccessor.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processDerivedId(EntityAccessor.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processAccessorsWithDerivedIDs(MetadataProject.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1992)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: The NPE isn't all that useful and should be filed as a bug so it throws something better, but logging at fine or finest should show you the class it was processing when it encountered the error. You might try simplifying your model, by removing the leaf classes and seeing which level of nesting it has a problem with - there could be an issue in your Address setup for instance.

Comment: As mentioned, one layer of embeddables works fine. Only the second layer causes issues. I don't know whether I have to treat the second layer in a different way.